# Why do I need the gem in the host application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, sass, rails-engines

I'm developing my first Rails Engine. It's an admin panel layout with assets and basic functionality.

What I really want is for it to be based on Twitter Bootstrap + SASS.

If I just have these lines in my gemspec file of my engine:

```
  gem.add_dependency "railties", "~> 3.2"
  gem.add_dependency "sass-rails"
  gem.add_dependency "bootstrap-sass"
```

I get this error when trying to access a page:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'bootstrap'
  (in /Users/swamiatma/Documents/Dropbox/coding/ruby/gems/tkh_admin_panel/app/assets/javascripts/admin.js:9)):
```

However if I add this to the host application gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

So that I get the following lines:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
end
```

It now works fine. I think this dependency belongs strictly to the Rails engine gem and should just be there.

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at 'rails-admin' engine. It is using 'bootstrap-sass' and it requires it in engine.rb : https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/engine.rb

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the important line in rails_admin/engine.rb (at least in my case) was the following:

```
require 'bootstrap-sass'
```

After I added this to my engine.rb, the error went away for me.